# HC 05 Bluetooth module with arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, hc-05

i want to know for executing "Bluetooth.available();" 
how much time is required, if connection is available, also in case of non availability of connection how much time is spent.

also for

Bluetooth.read() ;
Bluetooth.println("LED On!");

How much time is required .

my project is time sensitive so asking . kindly help

part of my code :::::::

```
     #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
   SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(10, 9); // RX, TX
  int LED = 13; // the on-board LED
  int Data; // the data received

     void setup() {
      Bluetooth.begin(9600);
     Serial.begin(9600);
     Serial.println("Waiting for command...");
      Bluetooth.println("Send 1 to turn on the LED. Send 0 to turn Off");
       pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);

     }

       void loop() {
        if (Bluetooth.available()){ //wait for data received
        Data=Bluetooth.read();
         if(Data=='1'){  
        digitalWrite(LED,1);
        Serial.println("LED On!");
    Bluetooth.println("LED On!");
```

Answer (score 0):

> how much time is required, if connection is available, also in case of non availability of connection how much time is spent.

**None!** `available()` and `read()` return immediately. SoftwareSerial itself burdens the controller a little bit, while data is being read or written. While sending at 9600 (which takes 1 ms per character), other things can happen in parallel, if the send buffer is not yet full.
However SoftwareSerial cannot work full duplex, so while writing, nothing can be read.